# jQuery event not firing on dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

I an using ASP.NET MVC 4 to dynamically load a PartialView which contains  a  option. I want to bind a jQuery dblclick event to this and get the selected option, but the event is not firing. Here is my code:

```
 <select size="5" id="popup-list">
     <option value="test">test</option>
 </select>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#popup-list").live("dblclick", function () {
        var name;
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            name = this;
            name = this.text();
        });
    });

});
```

I am not sure as the why this is causing a problem. The code is in a document.ready(), which should take care of the dynamic loading.

Comment: it is event delegation issuue. read more here  . http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: which version of jquery you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `On` method of jquery.

```
$("body").on("dblclick", "#popup-list", function () {
    var name;
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        name = this;
        name = this.text();
    });
});
```

Note: `on` method available on jquery version 7 onwards

Answer (score 2):

Try one of this:
Method:1

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#popup-list").on("dblclick", function () {
        var name;
        $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            name = this;
            name = this.text();
        });
    });
});
```

Method:2 Or

```
$(document.body).on("dblclick", '#popup-list', function () {
---your code----
});
```

Method:3

```
$(document).on("dblclick", '#popup-list', function () {
---your code----
});
```